# What is the least amount of questions to find out the number that a person is thinking between 1 to 1000 when they are allowed to lie at most once

Tags: puzzle, information-theory

A person is thinking of a number between 1 and 1000. What is the least number of yes/no questions that we can ask and know what that person's number is given that the person is allowed to lie on at most one of her answers.

Comment: Clearly the least number is two: Ask twice whether the number is $1$. The more interesting questions would be about the average case and the worst case.

Comment: This PDF should be helpful: [link](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gordon/ysp/bsearch.pdf)

Comment: Here's a strategy that requires $15$ questions in the worst case, which according to dtldarek's calculation is either optimal or nearly optimal: Do a standard binary search that requires $10$ questions. After the first $4$ questions, ask whether there was a lie in those $4$ answers. Then ask again after the next $3$ answers, then after $2$ and then after $1$. When a lie is detected, reask those questions. No matter when a lie is detected, it costs you $5$ additional questions in each case.

Comment: @joriki:  it is not specified, but I would take it that you are only allowed to ask questions about whether the number is in some set, not about whether the lie has happened.  I like the 15,11 Hamming approach

Comment: @RossMillikan: I agree with your interpretation of what kind of questions are (implicitly) assumed to be be valid, with questions about the persons own truthfulness you might get into circular situations. But in the scenario joriki proposes there is range such that the mentioned questions were answered truthfully _if and only if_ the value lies in that range. So rather than ask about truthfulness, one could ask about that range.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen:  good point.

Comment: As a theorem from [this PDF](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gordon/ysp/bsearch.pdf):

Theorem $5.2$
Let
$A$ and Q play the game on $[1, n]$. Assume that $Q$ can ask Boolean queries and that A can lie once. Then there is a strategy for Q that finds the number in
$≤ \log_2n+ \log_2 \log_2 n+O(1)$ steps.

Answer (score 7):

This is known as Ulam's problem of searching with lies.  For one lie it was first solved by Andrzej Pelc.  The minimum number of questions is not hard to calculate but the strategy attaining this number in the worst case takes several pages to describe.  Later the solution was simplified.

For $n$ objects with $1$ lie, $n$ even, the number $q$ of questions needed is the smallest solution to $\frac{2^q}{q+1} \geq n$ which is $14$ when $n=1000$.  There is a non-adaptive solution using Hamming codes that uses at most one more question than Pelc's method, but can specify all the questions before gameplay begins.

Comment: This (about the Hamming codes) is exactly what my intuition was telling me, thanks for the references!

Comment: @dtldarek -- another ref. : there was an article by Joel Spencer in Mathematics Magazine about the coding theory approach to the nonadaptive case.  Also Pelc's webpage has a publication list, with papers on the case with 2 lies and other variations.

Answer (score 4):

For distinguishing from $n$ options we need $\lceil \log_2 n \rceil$ bits of information. However, when we allow some bit to be faulty, we get $nk$ possibilities where $k$ is the number of asked questions. Optimally we would have to use at least logarithm of it, so

$$k = \log_2 (n k)$$

which with $n = 1000$ could be solved numerically, with appropriate ceils we get $k = 14$. This is the lower bound, that is, in the worst case we can't get the answer with smaller number of questions (there might be, of course, better lower bounds). To get the upper bound you can apply the [coding theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_theory), some sample approaches include "repeat every question 2 times", which will get you something like $2\lceil\log_2 n\rceil+1$ questions ($21$ for $n = 1000$), or search for the faulty place with binary search, arriving at about $\lceil\log_2 n\rceil +\big\lceil\log_2\lceil\log_2 n\rceil\big\rceil+1$ questions ($15$ for $n = 1000$).

I hope this helps ;-)

**Edit:** [Hamming(15,11) code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code) corrects 1 error and achieves even better bound: you would be able to distinguish $2^{11} = 2048$ possibilities. Of course, it also applies in your case.

Comment: $15$ questions is indeed possible; see my comment under the question.

Comment: @joriki Nice. I was thinking about a bit more universal approach. For example one should not do a simple binary search, but ask for something like "is the 3rd bit of binary expansion equal to 1" or "does $n \in [0..4) \cup [8..12) \cup [16..20) \cup \ldots$", etc. Such questions could be then reused. Also, I think you _can_ explicitly ask where the lie is (the adversary may lie only _one_ time), moreover you can even start "I will ask these 15 questions (now all the strategies are fixed), let the question in which you lie have index $l$, is the 2nd bit of binary expansion of $l$ equal to 1"?:)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick proof that it cannot be done in $13$ questions. Suppose there was a strategy that could do this; we may safely assume that $13$ questions are asked in all cases (just fill up with dummy questions if you happen to know the answer earlier). Then after $13$ questions, one will have found out both the number the person was thinking of, *and* the number of the answer that was a lie (taking $0$ if there was no lie). But the person may start with deciding both on the number and the number of the question that she will lie to. That gives $1000\times14>2^{13}=8192$ possibilities, too much to sort out using $13$ yes/no answers.

By this argument it still remains possible that $14$ questions will do, as $15000<2^{14}=16384$.