# Error correcting binary partition

Tags: recreational-mathematics, information-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Let's say I have a collection of $2^n$ labeled objects, and I want to find one of them. If I can ask yes-no questions about it, binary partition would immediatly lead us to the desired object in $n$ steps. But what if *noise* is introduced in our search?

For example, what would be the lowest number of searches so that we can always resist at most a single error for a given $n$? Two? $m$ errors? And finally, is this linkeable with error correcting codes theory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the least amount of questions to find out the number that a person is thinking between 1 to 1000 when they are allowed to lie at most once](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329238/what-is-the-least-amount-of-questions-to-find-out-the-number-that-a-person-is-th)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem of "Searching with Lies", first posed by Ulam.
Near-optimal solutions exist using error-correcting codes, but the exact answer is known only for very small number of lies and is a combinatorial tour de force.  More details in earlier answer here:

[What is the least amount of questions to find out the number that a person is thinking between 1 to 1000 when they are allowed to lie at most once](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329238/what-is-the-least-amount-of-questions-to-find-out-the-number-that-a-person-is-th/329436#329436)

Comment: One last question: Is there any easier way to prove this for the special case $2^n$?Thanks in advance

Comment: For special powers of $2$ that match the parameters of the Hamming code, using the code is the optimal strategy, and is non-adaptive (you can state the questions before the game begins).  That is, $q=2^a - 1$ questions to find one item from a set of $n = \frac{2^q}{q+1}$.